# How to get the number of time a user visit a page?

Tags: javascript

Does anyone have any idea about how to get the number of time a user visit a particular site? For instance, if you do a search on google and there's a link that you clicked already, google will tell you how many times you have visited that particular link. Any ideas on how to code something like that using javascript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Google's case they can track that you have clicked on a link. Its a specific action that they can attach a javascript listener to. If you want to do the same thing on your own site, you can add some javascript that does something similar, and anytime a link is clicked an AJAX call can be made that will allow you to track that it was clicked.

However, if you are just looking to get some basic stats about pages on your site you can add Google Analytics to it, and it will gather a large amount of useful data for you.

http://www.google.com/analytics/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know how many people are visiting your page, you probably want to check out something like [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) rather than making it yourself. It will give you a lot of data that you'd have to make a lot of effort to gather yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. And how about if I want to track a particular user and return how many times this user visited the page, how would I do that?

Comment: Well you need to be aware of privacy issues. People don't like to have their online behavior monitored too closely. Google Analytics doesn't let you track individual users, but it will tell you how many unique visitors, new visitors, etc. are coming to your site.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. I just want to know how to do it. Would it be possible to set a count in the user's cookie and retrieve it at each time?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Of course it means the count would be reset if the cookie is deleted, but maybe that's not an issue for you.

Comment: You can set/access cookies in javascript using "document.cookie". If you're using something like jQuery it should be trivial I guess. Try this for example: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie